# Having trouble Selenium testing date input where the input has a max and min date

Tags: java, selenium, jsp, selenium-webdriver

The max and min dates are set like:

```
        modelMap.addAttribute("minDate", new LocalDate().minusWeeks(1).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    modelMap.addAttribute("maxDate", new LocalDate().plusWeeks(1).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

The JSP is:

```
            <form:input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" 
                            min="${minDate}" max="${maxDate}" path="date"/>
```

For the selenium test, set up the date in the form like so:

```
    public void setDate(Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    Selenium.sendKeysToElement(dateField, str);
}
```

It works fine when i remove the min and max dates from the JSP, but the test doesn't work when they are their. I think it's because of the formatting.

Comment: What are the _max_ and _min_ date values ?

Comment: They're basically next week and last week respectively. In the format of 2019-08-06, yyyy-mm-dd as that was the only format that works with input type date

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```